# make rule for no extension from wildcard subdirectory

Tags: makefile, wildcard, subdirectory, rules

I have a bunch of targets that are built with the same type of make rule:

```
   env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/foo foo/*.go
   env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/bar bar/*.go
   env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/hello hello/*.go
   env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/world world/*.go
```

and I was trying to write one generic rule, based on

- [Makefile pattern rule for no extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718653/makefile-pattern-rule-for-no-extension)
- [make wildcard subdirectory targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932904/make-wildcard-subdirectory-targets)

Here is what I come up so far (but not working):

```
DIRS =$(filter %/, $(wildcard */))

build: $(DIRS)
    export GO111MODULE=on

bin/%: %/$(wildcard *.go)
    env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/$@ $@/*.go
```

Comment: You've been active on this site far too long to describe a problem as *"not working".* Does your makefile construct `DIRS` properly? Do you want it to be a list of all directories containing files with names ending in `.go`?

Comment: That's right @Beta, I want DIRS to be a list of all go source directories (that containing files with names ending in .go), but I don't know how to validate if makefile construct DIRS properly. By _"not working"_ I meant not working -- removing a file in bin and invoke make again but the file is ***not*** built.

Comment: "Not working" could mean 10,000 different things.  You should state _specifically_ what you mean.  Clearly describing the problem is the most fundamental requirement for asking an answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) to find all files whose names end in `.go`:

```
FILES := $(wildcard */*.go)

$(info Files are $(FILES)) # displays the contents of FILES, for debugging
```

Then we remove the file names, strip the trailing slashes and prepend `bin/` by means of [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
TARGS := $(patsubst %/, bin/%,$(dir $(FILES)))
```

We write a [PHONY](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) `all` rule that requires all of these targets:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGS)
```

and a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) to build them, using [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
bin/%:
    env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o $@ $*/*.go
```

Comment: You probably want to add a `$(sort ...)` to the setting of `TARGS` to avoid duplicates when directories contain multiple `.go` files.  It doesn't really hurt to list the same prerequisite multiple times to `all` but if you used this `TARGS` in other places it might matter.

Comment: @MadScientist: I considered that, but didn't want to make the solution too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Beta's answer gives you a solution to your problem but doesn't explain why your solution can't work:

```
DIRS =$(filter %/, $(wildcard */))
```

I'm not sure what the `filter` is for here.  It doesn't seem to do anything.
This will evaluate to a list of all the subdirectories, not just the subdirectories containing `.go` files, on most systems.  However some systems don't list only directories if you give just `/`.  A more reliable way to list all subdirectories would be:

```
DIRS := $(patsubst %/.,%,$(wildcard */.))
```

Note also I used `:=` so this is evaluated only once per make invocation, instead of every time the `DIRS` variable is evaluated.

```
build: $(DIRS)
        export GO111MODULE=on
```

This declares a target `build` which depends on all `DIRS`, but the recipe here is useless.  It starts a shell, runs that export in the shell, then the shell exits and the export is gone again.  It's not possible for a program (any program, not just make) to modify the environment of its parent process.

```
bin/%: %/$(wildcard *.go)
        env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/$@ $@/*.go
```

First, the `$(wildcard *.go)` is expanded when the makefile is parsed, like all targets and prerequisites.  So this expands to the list of all `.go` files in the *current* directory.  I assume there are none and so this expands to nothing.  If there were some it would be even worse; suppose you had `foo.go` and `bar.go` in the current directory; then this would expand to:

```
bin/%: %/foo.go bar.go
```

which is clearly wrong.

Second, you are using `$@` in the recipe but `$@` expands to the entire target, which is `bin/foo` for whatever directory `foo` you have.  So `bin/$@` expands to `bin/bin/foo` which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, exactly what I need to understand where my mistakes are.